# Create exact type d-dimension points, segments, etc... in using CGAL

Tags: cgal

Here is how I create 2D points with various precisions by using CGAL

```
#include <CGAL/Cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>

typedef CGAL::Cartesian<float> Kernel_float; 
typedef Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel_exact; 

typedef Kernel_float::Point_2 Point_2_float; 
typedef Kernel_exact::Point_2 Point_2_exact;
```

Here is how I create d-dimension 32-bit floating-point type point

```
#includee <CGAL/Cartesian_d.h>

typedef CGAL::Cartesian_d<float> Kernel_d_float; 

typedef Kernel_d_float::Point_d Point_d_float;
```

However, I cannot create exact type of Point_d... Since there is no header file like

```
CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel_d.h
```

Doesn't CGAL support exact type of d-dimension kernels?

Comment: Use `CGAL::Gmpq` instead of `float` and the kernel will be exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an exact dD-kernel, use a exact number type with `CGAL::Cartesian_d`, for example:

```
#include <CGAL/Cartesian_d.h>
#include <CGAL/Gmpq.h>

typedef CGAL::Cartesian_d<CGAL::Gmpq> Exact_kernel_d;
```